# What do you think is the best SharePoint Expo / Convention to go to in the USA 2017?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

If there is one to go to which one would be the best all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit

Microsoft Ignite- https://ignite.microsoft.com/#fbid=Hf3deA9Smwc

SharePoint Fest (Washington Convention Center):http://www.sharepointfest.com/DC/

SharePoint Tech (Dallas): http://10times.com/sharepoint-techfest-dallas

SPTechcon :http://www.sptechcon.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can visit Microsoft Ignite (September 25–29, 2017, Orlando, FL) ,pre-register on https://ignite.microsoft.com/#fbid=Hf3deA9Smwc

Also see http://www.sptechcon.com/